# Change default blade templates position on disk

Tags: templates, laravel-4, laravel-blade

Is there a way to change the default position of the blade template files on disk?

on a stock installation, doing something like

`View::make('list')`

looks for the file `list.blade.php` in the directory `app/views`

Lets say that we want these to be on the `public/templates` directory (I know, its bad practices, but lets just accept that for the sake of the example).

Any clues on how this can be accomplished?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer my question - one of the situations where the answer is just in front of you but for some reason you cannot seem to find it - you can set that in:

`config/views.php`

you can add as many paths as you wish there.